# Howto write unittests for struts 2 annotated based validation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, struts2, annotations

I am using annotation based validation in Struts 2.1.8.1.

Now i want to write a unit-test using jUnit 4 for them but have not got a clue how to do it.

I found several links which worked in Struts 2.1.6 but not in Struts 2.1.8.1 anymore:
http://bloodredsun.blog.com/2009/10/21/unit-testing-struts2-actions-with-annotation-based-validation/

Has anyone found a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
public class MyTestCase extends StrutsSpringTestCase {
    @Override
    protected String getContextLocations() {
        return "classpath*:applicationContext-test.xml";
    }
}


@Test
    public void testMyActionMapping() {
        final ActionMapping mapping = this.getActionMapping("/uriMap");
        Assert.assertNotNull(mapping);
        Assert.assertEquals("/uriMap", mapping.getNamespace());
        Assert.assertEquals("uriMap", mapping.getName());

        final ActionProxy proxy = this.getActionProxy("/uriMap");

        final MyAction action = MyAction.class.cast(proxy);
    }
```